# Is there a macros to see my code in runtime?

Tags: scala, debugging, macros, scala-macros, stringification

For debugging purposes, I want to print the passed argument, like

```
def myfunc(arg: MyType) = println(str_macro(arg) + " = " + arg)
```

I know, [I can define mine own](http://www.warski.org/blog/2012/12/starting-with-scala-macros-a-short-tutorial/). But, the thing seems to be standard. Is is supplied by standard libs?

Comment: You do know that if `myfunc` is not a macro itself, the code for `arg` will be quite disappointing? - it will simply be something like a `ValDef` (my guess) and does not at all reflect what you are sending there from the call-site. That information is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is one in the standard library, but see https://github.com/adamw/scala-macro-debug and https://github.com/vn971/macro-format (you can also do [`show(reify(arg).tree)`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#inspecting-trees)). Note that in this case, as 0__ says, the code for `arg` is going to be just `arg`!

Comment: Yes, we need `QUOTE(arg)` instead of `debug_print(arg)`.